# Customize GitLab slack integration messages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, slack

Is it possible to change the automatic slack notifications on "Receive event notifications in Slack"?

For example, if a pipeline has successfully completed, we get the following message from the Webhook:

> User/Project Name: Pipeline #269 of tag Ticket_8088 by User-Name
>   (User) passed in 12:02

The form of the message should be different.

I am the server administrator. So I can also change something at the code level. (if required)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a programmatic way to accomplish such task.

All messages are hardcoded in `app/models/project_services/chat_message` (as you can see [in the repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/app/models/project_services/chat_message)).

So, in your case, you need to change the method `activity` in `app/models/project_services/chat_message/pipeline_message.rb` - please consider that your changes will be discarded when you update GitLab.